# Can't adjust Javascript quote rotator initial quote load time of first quote

Tags: javascript, timer, slider, setinterval

I'm having issues with a simple quote rotator. The time between quotes is perfect, and I can adjust that. However I need to be adjust the initial load time of the first quote separately. It's on the same timer as the rest of the quotes, and the initial quote needs to populate upon page load. I'm not sure what to add to this Javascript code to accomplish that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var $quotes = $(".quote").hide(),
    timer = 3000,
    interval;

var quoteRotate = function(){
    $quotes.filter(".current").fadeIn(timer, function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $next = ($(this).next().length > 0) ? $this.next() : $quotes.first();
        $this.fadeOut(timer, function(){
            $this.removeClass('current');
            $next.addClass('current');
        });
    });
};

interval = setInterval(quoteRotate, timer * 2.05);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the initial delay like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $quotes = $(".quote").hide(),
        timer = 3000,
        initialDelay = 0,  //adjust initial delay as needed
        interval;
    
    var quoteRotate = function(){
        $quotes.filter(".current").fadeIn(timer, function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var $next = ($(this).next().length > 0) ? $this.next() : $quotes.first();
            $this.fadeOut(timer, function(){
                $this.removeClass('current');
                $next.addClass('current');
            });
        });
    };
    
    setTimeout( function() {
        quoteRotate();
        interval = setInterval(quoteRotate, timer * 2.05);
    }, initialDelay);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote current">"This is a quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is another quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is yet another quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is the fourth quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is the fifth quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is the sixth quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is the seventh quote" -somebody</div>
<div class="quote">"This is the 8th quote" -somebody</div>
```

I've set it to zero here, because it seemed like that was what you might want, but obviously you can adjust it to suit. Of course if that's all you want, just add a call to `quoteRotate()` right before you set the interval:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $quotes = $(".quote").hide(),
    timer = 3000,
    interval;

var quoteRotate = function(){
    $quotes.filter(".current").fadeIn(timer, function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var $next = ($(this).next().length > 0) ? $this.next() : $quotes.first();
        $this.fadeOut(timer, function(){
            $this.removeClass('current');
            $next.addClass('current');
        });
    });
};

quoteRotate(); //Show the first quote immediately.
interval = setInterval(quoteRotate, timer * 2.05);
});
```